# Spark-SQL dataframe count gives java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a dataframe using Apache Spark version 2.3.1. When I try to count a dataframe I get following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 12, analitik11.{hostname}, executor 1): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch.column(ColumnarBatch.java:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.datasourcev2scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1602)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1823)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1772)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1761)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:297)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2770)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2769)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3253)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2769)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
  at org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch.column(ColumnarBatch.java:98)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.datasourcev2scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We use `com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder` to connect to and read tables from Hive. Code for generating the dataframe is as follows:

```
    val hive = com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder.session(spark).build() 

    val edgesTest = hive.executeQuery("select trim(s_vno) as src ,trim(a_vno) as dst, share, administrator, account, all_share " +
      "from ebyn.babs_edges_2018 where (share <> 0 or administrator <> 0 or account <> 0 or all_share <> 0) and trim(date) = '201801'")

    val share_org_edges = edgesTest.alias("df1").
                                             join(edgesTest.alias("df2"), "src").
                                             where("df1.dst <> df2.dst").
                                             groupBy(
                                                  greatest("df1.dst", "df2.dst").as("src"), 
                                                  least("df1.dst", "df2.dst").as("dst")).
                                             agg(max("df1.share").as("share"), max("df1.administrator").as("administrator"), max("df1.account").as("account"), max("df1.all_share").as("all_share")).persist

share_org_edges.count
```

Table properties are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `EBYN.BABS_EDGES_2018`(                                         
   `date` string,                                                            
   `a_vno` string,                                                            
   `s_vno` string,                                                            
   `amount` double,                                                        
   `num` int,                                                            
   `share` int,                                                               
   `share_ratio` int,                                                            
   `administrator` int,                                                            
   `account` int,                                                            
   `share-all` int)                                                        
 COMMENT 'Imported by sqoop on 2018/10/11 11:10:16'                           
 ROW FORMAT SERDE                                                             
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'                       
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (                                                       
   'field.delim'='',                                                         
   'line.delim'='\n',                                                         
   'serialization.format'='')                                                
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                                        
   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'                                 
 OUTPUTFORMAT                                                                 
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'               
 LOCATION                                                                     
   'hdfs://ggmprod/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/ebyn.db/babs_edges_2018' 
 TBLPROPERTIES (                                                              
   'bucketing_version'='2',                                                   
   'transactional'='true',                                                    
   'transactional_properties'='insert_only',                                  
   'transient_lastDdlTime'='1539245438')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**
The `edgesTest` is a dataframe with a logical plan containing a unique `DataSourceV2Relation` node. This `DataSourceV2Relation` logical plan node contains a mutable `HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader` that will be used to read the Hive table.
The `edgesTest` dataframe is used two times : as `df1` and as `df2`.
During Spark logical plan optimization, column pruning happened two times on the same `HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader` mutable instance. The second column pruning overwriting the first one by setting its own required columns.
During execution the reader will fire two times the same query to Hive warehouse with the columns required by the second column pruning. The Spark generated code will not find the expected columns from Hive query result.

**Solutions**
**Spark 2.4**
`DataSourceV2` has been improved, especially by [SPARK-23203 DataSourceV2 should use immutable trees](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23203)

**Spark 2.3**
Disable column pruning in the `HiveWarehouseConnector` datasource reader.

Hortonworks has already fixed this issue, as stated by the [HDP 3.1.5 Release Notes](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/release-notes/content/fixed_issues.html).
We can find the correction in its [HiveWarehouseConnector github repository](https://github.com/hortonworks/hive-warehouse-connector-release/tree/HDP-3.1.5.1-2-tag) :

```java
    if (useSpark23xReader) {
      LOG.info("Using reader HiveWarehouseDataSourceReaderForSpark23x with column pruning disabled");
      return new HiveWarehouseDataSourceReaderForSpark23x(params);
    } else if (disablePruningPushdown) {
      LOG.info("Using reader HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader with column pruning and filter pushdown disabled");
      return new HiveWarehouseDataSourceReader(params);
    } else {
      LOG.info("Using reader PrunedFilteredHiveWarehouseDataSourceReader");
      return new PrunedFilteredHiveWarehouseDataSourceReader(params);
    }
```

Also, the [HDP 3.1.5 Hive integration doc](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/integrating-hive/hive_integrating_hive_and_bi.pdf) specify :

> To prevent data correctness issues in this release, pruning and projection pushdown is disabled by default.
>   ...
>   To prevent these issues and ensure correct results, do not enable pruning and pushdowns.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and even after disabling data pruning / pushdown, it doesn't work..

The documentation is found here https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/integrating-hive/content/hive-read-write-operations.html under **Pruning and Pushdowns**

in Python I set:
spark.conf.set('spark.datasource.hive.warehouse.disable.pruning.and.pushdowns', 'true')

But this doesnt work. Instead I have found a solution/workaround which is to persist one of the tables (which was identified to be faulty).

df1 = df.filter(xx).join(xx)**.persist()**

I guess from the documentation, spark does project pushdown to find the parent dataframe - this error occurs when joining df of the same dataframe, can someone explain it?

Also, let me know if it works